# Error concatenating layers in the generator in a GAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am making a GAN (in deep learning) in tensor flow Keras. The generator is a UNET architecture: we downsample the image input into smaller and deeper matrix, then we upsample to restore the size. Here is the code for the generator:

```
OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 3
def downsample(filters,size,apply_batchnorm = True):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0,0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                             size,
                             strides=2,
                             padding='same',
                             kernel_initializer=initializer,
                             use_bias=False)
  )

  if apply_batchnorm:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
  
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())

  return result
def upsample(filters,size,apply_dropout = False):
  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0,0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
          filters,
          size,
          strides=2,
          padding='same',
          kernel_initializer=initializer,
          use_bias = False
      )
  )
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  if apply_dropout:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  
  return result
def Generator():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256,256,1])

  down_stack = [                       #Output Size
               downsample(32,4,False), 
               downsample(64,4,True) #128
  ]

  up_stack = [                         #Output&Channel Size
             upsample(32,4),           #128 128
             upsample(32,4)
  ]

  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0,0.2)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
      OUTPUT_CHANNELS,
      4,
      2,
      padding = 'same',
      kernel_initializer = initializer,
      activation = 'tanh'
  )

  x = inputs

  skips = []
  for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)
  
  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  for up,skip in zip(up_stack,skips):
    x = up(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x,skip])
  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=x)
generator = Generator()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(generator,show_shapes=True,dpi=64)
```

Here is the model, you can see that at concatenate_6 (the first concatenate), the dimensions are equal

[image]

When I run it for an input of a gray image (256x256x1)  `generator(example_input, training=True)`, it says the following error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'concatenate_6' (type Concatenate).
    
    Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 2 and 1. Shapes are [32,128,2] and [32,128,1]. for '{{node model_7/concatenate_7/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](model_7/sequential_29/leaky_re_lu_30/LeakyRelu, model_7/sequential_27/leaky_re_lu_28/LeakyRelu, model_7/concatenate_7/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [32,128,2,32], [32,128,1,32], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <3>.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'concatenate_4' (type Concatenate):
      • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 128, 2, 32), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 128, 1, 32), dtype=float32)']
```

I make the layers down and up the same, how is it possible that there is a discrepancy, please help!

Comment: `shape[0] = [256,2,2,512] vs. shape[1] = [256,2,1,512]` is pretty clear, you are concatenating two things along a dimension that is not valid... so either you misscalculated the dimensions, or you want `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)`

Comment: what does `axis=2` do?

Comment: tells the layer on which dimension you want the tensors to be concatenated

Comment: I want to concatenate the whole thing, two output together

Comment: yes but if you have 2 matrices (example), you can concatenate along 2 different dimensions

Comment: if I put `axis=2` it messes up all the output dimension, not an output image anymore. too bad if I put `axis=0` the error persists. you can see that I put the upsample dimension to be equal to the downsample right, hard to see where I got it wrong

Comment: give a name to the concatenate layers and see in the error which is causing the problem... also consider providing a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I added an image, it says the error in concatenate_28 (the first concatenate), but in the image, the dimensions are equal

Comment: then check the shape of the input you are giving the network

Comment: the shape is 256x256x1, can't be wrong on that

Comment: I updated with a minimal example